# MacBook unable to visit websites while connected to Wifi

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, vpn, proxy

A month ago I made a wrong manipulation in the Network settings of my computer and since then I cannot browse any websites nor use the Mail app when I connect to my office’s WiFi or at the local café. There, I need to connect to my phone’s 4G in order to browse and check my emails normally, which obviously consumes a lot of data. Another way to be able connect there is to use a VPN. But without the VPN activated, I'm unable to connect.

When I am at home, it connects normally. So there is somewhere some incompatibility with other networks. Is it a DNS or proxy problem ? How can I solve this ?

Please help !

Comment: "I made a wrong manipulation in the Network settings" raises the question - what specific 'manipulations' did you make and did you revert them back or not.

Comment: Hi, I changed the IPv4 address manually in the TCP/IP tab of the Advanced settings in the WiFi settings in the Network menu of my Mac. I also deleted previous DNS servers and added new ones. I also unticked all boxes in the Proxys tab. Sadly I don't have a record of what was there previously. But I can tell you what is there now :
TCP/IP : Via DHCP
IPv4 : 172.20.10.2
Sub-network : 255.255.255.240
Router : 172.20.10.1

DNS Server : 192.168.1.252

I did that before to be able to connect to a European sever of an online game, since I could not join it because I am in China.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the Wi-Fi service in network settings and then adding it again? That would give you a clean slate where DHCP can do its thing and the network you connect to can set the DNS.

Comment: @root I have deleted ("forgotten" as Mac calls this) my office WiFi and added it again after. No success. However I notice that the information is now different in the TCP/IP tab for this WiFi service : IPv4 is 192.168.1.44, sub-network is 255.255.255.0 and router is 192.168.1.1. But I'm still unable to browse any website while connected to this WiFi. Is it a DNS or Proxy problem then ?

Comment: @mattvent I'd expect the DNS to be automatically picked up but you could try Google's DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).

Answer (score -1):

This seems to happen when software update of the Mac or update of the iPhone is necessary. Then it happens at other times.  So, I started synching my iPhone with the Mac through Music.  The problem stopped.  May be it is a way to remind us to synch the phone with the Mac air. The answers of bad charger wire, dirty charging point, etc. are probably valid, but not the final answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I know it's not a random problem. It happened specifically after I tried to change the DNS settings of my computer to connect to an online game, about 2 months ago. Since then, browsers and the Mail app stopped working outside my home. However, I have no idea how to fix that.